# Can i use Qt Virtual Keyboard?

Tags: gpl, lgpl

Is this design correct?

System Qt 5 has [qtvirtualkeyboard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-index.html#licenses-and-attributions) thich is GPL.

Can I link my proprietary app with system Qt?

Can I create open source app which run Qt Virtual Keyboard then load my app as module?

Answer (score 3):

The GPL is intended to cover the whole program. You cannot create a proprietary program that loads a GPL library. Where a GPL program loads a plugin, that plugin would be subject to the GPL as well.

The GPL FAQ addresses these questions in more detail:

- [If a library is released under the GPL (not the LGPL), does that mean that any software which uses it has to be under the GPL or a GPL-compatible license?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#IfLibraryIsGPL)
- [When is a program and its plug-ins considered a single combined program?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLPlugins)
- [If I write a plug-in to use with a GPL-covered program, what requirements does that impose on the licenses I can use for distributing my plug-in?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLAndPlugins)
- [Can I release a nonfree program that's designed to load a GPL-covered plug-in?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#NFUseGPLPlugins)

There is one caveat: these issues are not clear from copyright law, and there is no court precedent. This answer presents the Free Software Foundation's *opinion* on this matter. It is also possible to argue this differently, in particular that the GPL cannot extend to the entire program. But if you want to stay on the safe side of this grey area, you should assume that the FSF's interpretation is correct.

Comment: Can i use IPC ( DBUS or socket) between proprietary and open source parts?

Comment: @eri Probably yes, if there's a bright line between the GPL-covered program and the proprietary program that clearly shows that they are entirely separate programs. However, this is difficult to pull of correctly and safely. Note that you are still subject to the GPL for the GPL-covered program you will be writing.